# Search API sortlist order not working

Tags: search, rest

I have trying to fetch items for a particular content type and trying to sort the result based on two columns:

```
sortlist=%27DueDate:ascending,ProjectTitleOWSCHCS:ascending%27
```

Both the fields are searchable and sortable. However, it is not working as expected.
However, when only one column is specified, it works.

```
sortlist=%27ProjectTitleOWSCHCS:ascending%27
```

Comment: make them sortable as well like [this](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/article/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-custom-display-templates-for2/Images/23.png)

Comment: these are already sortable.